# Regex to match any character except a backslash

Tags: ruby, regex

How can i say "all symbols except backslash" in Ruby character class?

```
/'[^\]*'/.match("'some string \ hello'")  => should be nil
```

Variant with two backslashed doesn't work

```
/'[^\\]*'/.match("'some string \ hello'")  => 'some string \ hello' BUT should be nil
```

Comment: a great resource for Ruby regex debugging is: http://rubular.com/

Comment: yes, especially when irb is not available

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is not with your regex; you got that right. Your problem is that your test string **does not have a backslash in it**. It has an escaped space, instead. Try this:

```
str = "'some string \\ hello'"
puts str                 #=> 'some string \ hello'
p /'[^\\]*'/.match(str)  #=> nil
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
[^\\]*
```

because backslash is the escape character in regular expressions, thus escaping the closing bracket here.

If you want to verify that the whole string contains non-backslash characters, then you need anchors:

```
^[^\\]*$
```

Comment: I tried it before write this question, but it doesn't work. (ruby 1.9.2)

Comment: Well, it will match the part *before* the backslash

Comment: no, it matches whole string, i added single quotes to show it

Answer (score 3):

There's actually not a backslash in your string to match against. Try taking a look at just your input:

```
"'some string \ hello'".length # => 20 
"a\ b".length # => 3
```

The "\ " in double quotes is being escaped into just a space:

```
irb(main):014:0> " "[0].to_i # => 32
irb(main):015:0> "\ "[0].to_i # => 32
irb(main):016:0> "\ ".size #=> 1
```

If you want to match no slash, you'll need two, like in your second example, which looks good to me:

```
 /'[^\\]*'/.match("'some string \\ hello'") # => nil
```

Answer (score -1):

This is relevant to Csharp.. but idk it might help you.

```
[^\\\\]*
```

four slashes instead of two.